# Photo archiving from multiple folders

Tags: powershell

I am working on an archiving script and I could use some help, please, and thank you.

Folder Structure Layout:

```text
C:\Script_Testing\Photos_Folder\101\Accepted
C:\Script_Testing\Photos_Folder\101\Rejected
C:\Script_Testing\Photos_Folder\102\Accepted
C:\Script_Testing\Photos_Folder\102\Rejected
```

etc, etc.

All of the folders both Accepted and Rejected have PNG files. The files are coming in from multiple cameras which is why there are multiple numbered folders. I have the script (below) for organizing the photos. The script works if I were going to just run the script for a single folder (I hope that makes sense).

What I am trying to figure out is the following:

I only need to archive the pictures from the Accepted folders. I need the script to somehow recursively do what it is currently doing but only for folders:

```text
C:\Script_Testing\Photos_Folder\101\Accepted 
C:\Script_Testing\Photos_Folder\102\Accepted
C:\Script_Testing\Photos_Folder\103\Accepted
```

etc.

It needs to keep that same format during the archive process. When it currently archives it creates a set of folders (assuming the photos are from today):

```text
C:\Script_Testing\Archived_Photos\2022\6\10\6102022.zip
```

The format above works, but I need to also keep the 101, 102, 103, etc as well so I know what camera the photos came from.

I would like it to be archived like this:

```text
C:\Script_Testing\Archived_Photos\101\2022\6\10\6102022.zip
C:\Script_Testing\Archived_Photos\102\2022\6\10\6102022.zip
```

etc.

Is this possible to do?

Thank you guys for any help you can provide.

```sh
# Grab photos to be archived
$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Script_Testing\Photos_Folder' -Recurse | where { !$_.PsIsContainer }
    
# List of photos to be moved
$files
        
# Target where photos should be moved to. The script will automatically create a folder for the year, month, and date
$targetPath = 'C:\Script_Testing\Archived_Photos'
        
foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Get year and Month of the file
    $year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year.ToString()
    $month = $file.LastWriteTime.Month.ToString()
    $day = $file.LastWriteTime.Day.ToString()
        
    # Out FileName, year and month
    $file.Name
    $year
    $month
    $day
        
    # Set directory path structure
    $Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $year + "\" + $month + "\" + $day + "\"
    # Create directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!(Test-Path $Directory)) {
        New-Item $directory -type directory
    }
        
    # Move files to new location
    $file | Move-Item -Destination $Directory
        
    # Compress files by day then remove original PNG files.
    Compress-Archive -Path (Join-Path $directory *.png) -Update -DestinationPath ($Directory + (Get-Date -Format $day$month$year) + '.zip')
    Get-Item (Join-Path $directory *) -exclude *.zip | Remove-Item -WhatIf
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides inserting the `101`, `102` etc. folder in the path, your code could be more streamlines I guess by first do a loop to create the subfolders and move  the files, and then in a second loop do the compression/deleting instead of compressing each file as it comes along.

Something like this:

```
# Target where photos should be moved to. The script will automatically create a folder for the year, month, and date
$targetPath = 'C:\Script_Testing\Archived_Photos'
# Grab photos to be archived
$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Script_Testing\Photos_Folder\*\Accepted\*' -Filter '*.png' -File
  
$dirsToCompress = foreach ($file in $files) {
    $number = $file.DirectoryName.Split("\")[-2]  # e.g. 101
    # Set directory path structure
    $Directory = Join-Path -Path $targetPath -ChildPath ('{0}\{1:yyyy\\MM\\dd}' -f $number, $file.LastWriteTime)
    # Create directory if it doesn't exist
    $null = New-Item $directory -Type Directory -Force
    # move the file
    # for safety while testing, change this to `Copy-Item`
    $file | Move-Item -Destination $Directory
    # output the path to collect in $dirsToCompress
    $Directory
}

# now compress all files in the directories we have collected in $dirsToCompress
foreach ($folder in ($dirsToCompress | Select-Object -Unique)) {
    $zipTarget = Join-Path -Path $folder -ChildPath ('{0:ddMMyyyy}.zip' -f (Get-Date))
    $pngFiles  = Join-Path -Path $folder -ChildPath '*.png'
    Compress-Archive -Path $pngFiles -DestinationPath $zipTarget -Update
    Remove-Item -Path $pngFiles -Recurse -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.
I am still working through it trying to understand it all.
They just changed the folder structure on me at work today so I am going to do my best to work with the code above to make it work.

On this line `$number = $file.DirectoryName.Split("\")[-2]  # e.g. 101` is [-2] telling it to go back 2 directories?

Comment: @ChuckCogginsIII  Yes, `[-2]` gets the second-to-last item of the array. Index -1 would get the last item and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the help!
I was able to finally take a look at and test this out.
The guy who wanted me to work on this made a bunch of changes so I am going to hopefully take what you wrote and modify it to work the way he wants it to. They basically want to archive all the photos and not just the accepted stuff now.
Thank you again!